# Password-Protecting Elmah.axd file

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, elmah, axd

I've succesfully set up Elmah in my web project and I can access the crash log at 
http://www.myserver.com/Elmah.axd .

The only question is how to secure this URL so that only my colleagues (as opposed to anonymous users and users who are logged in, but not part of my team) can access it. ASP.NET forms authentication is already set up on the system.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phil Haack had a blog post about this:
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you have roles setup, you could use the web.config file to restrict access to that file only to people within a specified role.